# How to show that $(a/b)^2$ in this situation cannot be an integer

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a$,$b$ be relatively prime integers which are both greater than or equal to $2$
. Show that $(a/b)^2$ cannot be an integer.

I have tried to use contradiction to prove this result, but I am not sure that my idea is correct or not. Below is my idea (not a complete proof).

Suppose $(a/b)^2$ be an integer.
We have $a/b$ is an integer.
Then, we have $a=bk$ where $k$ is an integer since $b$ divides $a$.
Since $a,b$ are relatively prime, therefore $b$ must be $1$.
Hence, contradiction arises.
I am not sure that my idea is correct or not, could anyone help me to check it?
If my idea is wrong, could you give me a idea to do this question?

Comment: You already know that $a/b$ is not an integer. It seems to me what is really being asked is to show that if a rational number is not an integer, then neither is its square.

Comment: You have to exclude the case that $(a/b)^2=m$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: Your very first line is not quite right. If $(a/b)^2$ is integer, then it does not follow that $a/b$ is integer. Say, what if $(a/b)^2 = 2$?